# pointer to vector at index Vs iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

I have a **vector< Object > myvec** which I use in my code to hold a list of objects in memory. I keep a pointer to the current object in that vector in the "normal" **C** fashion by using

```
Object* pObj = &myvec[index];
```

This all works fine if... myvec doesn't grow big enough that it is moved around during a **push_back** at which time **pObj** becomes invalid - vectors guarantee data is sequential, hence they make no effort to keep the vector at the same memory location.

I can reserve enough space for myvec to prevent this, but I dnt' like that solution.

I could keep the index of the selected myvec position and when I need to use it just access it directly, but it's a costly modification to my code.

I'm wondering if iterators keep the their references intact as a vector is reallocated/moved and if so can I just replace

```
Object* pObj = &myvec[index];
```

by something like

```
vector<Object>::iterator = myvec.begin()+index;
```

What are the implication of this?

Is this doable?

What is the standard pattern to save pointers to vector positions?

Cheers

Comment: Keeping the index is "costly"? Meh.

Comment: The standard pattern to preserve iterators is to reserve space upfront, or use a container which preserves iterators.  There are compromises either way.

Comment: You say below that you "use vectors pretty much as arrays", which is exactly what you *should* be doing -- but I have a suspicion that your entire question is the consequence of some bad design decisions. Somehow this shouldn't be a problem at all... it's just hard to tell without knowing the context.

Comment: In what sense is using index a "costly modification"? Do you mean that you have too many lines to change? Or the run-time cost of `myvec[i]` is greater than the run-time cost of `*pObj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No... using an iterator you would have the same exact problem. If a vector reallocation is performed then all iterators are invalidated and using them is Undefined Behavior.

The only solution that is reallocation-resistant with an `std::vector` is using the integer index.

Using for example `std::list` things are different, but also the are different efficiency compromises, so it really depends on what you need to do.

Another option would be to create your own "smart index" class, that stores a reference to the vector and the index. This way you could keep just passing around one "pointer" (and you could implement pointer semantic for it) but the code wouldn't suffer from reallocation risks.

Comment: the problem is that lists don't have the [] operator and that sucks as I use vectors pretty much as an array.

Comment: @Andre: `std::deque` only invalidates iterators if you insert/remove at the middle.  `push_back` and `pop_back` will not invalidate.  They have `[]` and lookup speed is closer to `vector` than `list`.

Comment: @MooingDuck. Well, that seems to be the way to go. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @Andre: lists don't have the invalidation problem, though.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  From 23.3.3.4 [deque.modifiers]/p1:  An insertion at either end of the deque invalidates all the iterators to the deque.  p4 in the same section states that `pop_back()` (or erasing the last element) will invalidate the end iterator.

Comment: @MooingDuck As Howard pointed out, the part about iterator invalidation is incorrect, but replace “iterators” with “references (and pointers)” and it becomes correct.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are (potentially) invalidated by anything that could resize the vector (e.g., push_back).

You could, however, create your own iterator class that stored the vector *and* an index, which would be stable across operations that resized the vector:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace stable {

template <class T, class Dist=ptrdiff_t, class Ptr = T*, class Ref = T&>
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T, Dist, Ptr, Ref>
{
    T &container_;
    size_t index_;
public:
    iterator(T &container, size_t index) : container_(container), index_(index) {}

    iterator operator++() { ++index_; return *this; }
    iterator operator++(int) { iterator temp(*this); ++index_; return temp; }
    iterator operator--() { --index_; return *this; }
    iterator operator--(int) { stable_itertor temp(*this); --index_; return temp; }
    iterator operator+(Dist offset) { return iterator(container_, index_ + offset); }
    iterator operator-(Dist offset) { return iterator(container_, index_ - offset); }

    bool operator!=(iterator const &other) const { return index_ != other.index_; }
    bool operator==(iterator const &other) const { return index_ == other.index_; }
    bool operator<(iterator const &other) const { return index_ < other.index_; }
    bool operator>(iterator const &other) const { return index_ > other.index_; }

    typename T::value_type &operator *() { return container_[index_]; }
    typename T::value_type &operator[](size_t index) { return container_[index_ + index]; }
};

template <class T>
iterator<T> begin(T &container) { return iterator<T>(container, 0); }

template <class T>
iterator<T> end(T &container) { return iterator<T>(container, container.size()); }

}

#ifdef TEST
int main() { 

    std::vector<int> data;

    // add some data to the container:
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        data.push_back(i);

    // get iterators to the beginning/end:
    stable::iterator<std::vector<int> > b = stable::begin(data);
    stable::iterator<std::vector<int> > e = stable::end(data);

    // add enough more data that the container will (probably) be resized:
    for (int i=10; i<10000; i++)
        data.push_back(i);

    // Use the previously-obtained iterators:
    std::copy(b, e, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // These iterators also support most pointer-like operations:
    std::cout << *(b+125) << "\n";
    std::cout << b[150] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Since we can't embed this as a nested class inside of the container like a normal iterator class, this requires a slightly different syntax to declare/define an object of this type; instead of the usual `std::vector<int>::iterator whatever;`, we have to use `stable::iterator<std::vector<int> > whatever;`. Likewise, to obtain the beginning of a container, we use `stable::begin(container)`.

There is one point that *may* be a bit surprising (at least at first): when you obtain a `stable::end(container)`, that gets you the end of the container *at that time*. As shown in the test code above, if you later add more items to the container, the iterator your obtained previously is *not* adjusted to reflect the new end of the container -- it retains the position it had when you obtained it (i.e., the position that *was* the end of the container at that time, but isn't any more).

Answer (score 2):

No, iterators are invalidated after vector growth.

The way to get around this problem is to keep the index to the item, not a pointer or iterator to it. This is because the item stays at its index, even if the vector grows, assuming of course that you don't insert any items before it (thus changing its index).

Comment: To add, if you wish to keep iterators, maybe look into lists?

Comment: or `std::deque`, depending on what you do with it